# Webpack Config to build sdk for both Node and Browser

Tags: node.js, webpack

Can someone help me in figuring out what should be the webpack sdk config to build sdk for both web and browser?

My current config looks like this

```
const path = require('path');

let baseConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'sdk/js-sdk.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'jsSdk',
    globalObject: 'this'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  externals: {
    "request-promise-native": "request-promise-native",
    "request": "request"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = baseConfig
```

Which I am building using following command

```
  "pn-dev-build": "rm -rf dist && npm version patch && webpack --mode=development && npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873",
```

And then if I install it in my vue-nuxt project it gives following error

> - fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js                                                                                     friendly-errors 09:06:34
> - net in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js and 1 other
>     friendly-errors 09:06:34
> - tls in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js

Can someone help me in solving the above error?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple entry point approach is not the best idea here because you are bundling for two different targets(node and browser) with same config

Better would be to export a array with [two configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) something like this ( and in this approch you can use multiple entry point to split your browser bundle and other stuff to make your website performant )

in `webpack.config.js` ( use this file as Webpack config )

```
const webpackBrowserConfig = require("./webpack.config.browser.js");
const webpackServerConfig = require("./webpack.config.server.js");

module.exports = [webpackServerConfig, webpackBrowserConfig];
```

in `webpack.config.browser.js`

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // your browser related config
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  externals: {
    "request-promise-native": "request-promise-native",
    "request": "request"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

and in `webpack.config.server.js`

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/serverIndex.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    // your server related config
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  externals: {
    "request-promise-native": "request-promise-native",
    "request": "request"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

you can also create this in same file and reduce some duplication ( whichever works for you ) I showed this approach with two different file for clarity

Answer (score 0):

create a file as an entry point for the server, and another for the browser.

```
let baseConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: ['browser.ts','server.ts'],
  ...
}
```

browser.ts contains all browser-specific logic, and server.ts contains all server-specific logis.